# FindRoot and symbolic evaluation

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

Following the [Symbolic evaluation documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSymbolicEvaluation.html), I am trying to solve the equation:
$y'(x) = a*y(x), \quad y(0)=1$
where I later fix a via FindRoot, requiring that $y(2) = 2$:

```
ftest[unknown_?NumberQ] := First[y[2] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == unknown*y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 4}]] 
FindRoot[ftest[k] - 2, {k, 0, 4}]
```

This works well, but for some reason, replacing the "k" by "x" inside the Findroot outputs errors? I tried opening a new notebook and/or using Clear, but that did not solve the problem. Why does Mathematica treat x differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `x` within your `ftest` function, which is getting replaced by `FindRoot`. To fix this, you need to scope your `ftest` function. The following works:

```
ftest[unknown_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  First[y[2] /. 
    NDSolve[{y'[x] == unknown*y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 4}]]]
FindRoot[ftest[x] - 2, {x, 0, 4}]
```

If you read the error message your code outputs, you see something like `NDSolve::dsvar: 0. cannot be used as a variable`. `FindRoot` appears to be replacing the `x` in `NDSolve[..., {x, 0, 4}]` with `0`, resulting in `NDSolve[..., {0, 0, 4}]`, which is where it's trying to use `0` as a variable. Thus, you need to scope your inner `x` with a `Module` so that it doesn't get replaced.

Comment: The OP might note also that `ftest[x]` translates to the ODE `y'[x] == x*y[x]`, which is quite a bit different than when `unknown` is a constant.  However, in this case, as Carl points out, `FindRoot` replaces `x` by a number globally. This is what is meant by this line in the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html): "`FindRoot`...effectively uses `Block` to localize variables."

Comment: I see. I thought that inside function definition, the variables are automatically made local. Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot for the clarification. I don't have an extremely strong knowledge of the scoping mechanisms myself!